# WooCommerece single product page - remove duplicated tabs

Tags: php, tabs, woocommerce

Developing a tour website. Running for the cause child theme, with wooCommerece and wooDeposits.

I have just changed the layout of the single product page so that my 'tabs' which show 'your day includes' and reviews are at the top right of the page and the product summary where you select what you actually want to buy is below the tabs.  But instead of moving the tabs it has duplicated them so now they are above and below the summary.

The code I used on the function.php page was as follows:

```
// Removes tabs from their original loaction 
remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 10 );

// Inserts tabs under the main right product content 
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_product_data_tabs', 5 );
```

Can someone please tell me how to remove the second lot of tabs at the bottom of the screen??